# ASP.NET Core Web API : how to write logs for each users separately using Log4Net?

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-core-webapi, log4net

I need to know how to write log for each logged in users separately.

For example USER A, then the file should be created as `logs/USER A/06.02.2024.log`.

I am using Log4Net to write logs to file. Please support.

I need to write custom logging for each user's separately.
I tried the below code, but file not created.

```
 public class Log4NetLogger : ILogger
 {
     private readonly ILog _logger;

 public Log4NetLogger(ILog logger)
 {
     _logger = logger;
 }

 public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
 {
     return null; // No scope support in log4net
 }

 public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
 {
     switch (logLevel)
     {
         case LogLevel.Trace:
         case LogLevel.Debug:
             return _logger.IsDebugEnabled;
         case LogLevel.Information:
             return _logger.IsInfoEnabled;
         case LogLevel.Warning:
             return _logger.IsWarnEnabled;
         case LogLevel.Error:
             return _logger.IsErrorEnabled;
         case LogLevel.Critical:
             return _logger.IsFatalEnabled;
         default:
             throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(logLevel), logLevel, null);
     }
 }

 public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception,
     Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
 {
     if (!IsEnabled(logLevel))
     {
         return;
     }

     var message = formatter(state, exception);
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
     {
         return;
     }

     switch (logLevel)
     {
         case LogLevel.Trace:
         case LogLevel.Debug:
             _logger.Debug(message);
             break;
         case LogLevel.Information:
             _logger.Info(message);
             break;
         case LogLevel.Warning:
             _logger.Warn(message);
             break;
         case LogLevel.Error:
             _logger.Error(message, exception);
             break;
         case LogLevel.Critical:
             _logger.Fatal(message, exception);
             break;
         default:
             _logger.Warn($"Encountered unknown log level {logLevel}, writing out as Info.");
             _logger.Info(message, exception);
             break;
     }
 }
 }
}
```

And the custom class

```
public class CustomLoggerFactory : ILoggerFactory
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public CustomLoggerFactory(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public void AddProvider(ILoggerProvider provider)
    {
        // Do nothing or implement as needed
    }

    public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
    {
        var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(categoryName);

        var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;
        if (user != null && user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var userId = user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
            {
                var logFilePath = $"logs/{userId}/log.txt";
                var logFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(logFilePath);
                if (!Directory.Exists(logFolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(logFolder);
                }
                // Configure log4net to use the dynamic file path
                GlobalContext.Properties["LogFileName"] = logFilePath;
            }
        }

        return new Log4NetLogger(logger);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Dispose resources if needed
    }
}
```

And in startup

```
public static void ConfigureLogging(ILoggingBuilder loggingBuilder)
{
    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();
    loggingBuilder.AddLog4Net();
    loggingBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerFactory, CustomLoggerFactory>();
}
```

Comment: It would be nicer if you could share your exsist code snippet or what steps you have implemented. However, in order to write separate logs for each user in your ASP.NET Core Web API with Log4Net, create a configuration file including a dynamic username in the log file path and a dedicated "CustomUserLogger". Access the current user's identity in a middleware/filter and store it in ThreadContext. In your controllers/services, use the "CustomUserLogger" to write user-specific logs with the extracted username.

Comment: In addition, please [`refer to this  document for details implementation`](https://betterstack.com/community/guides/logging/how-to-start-logging-with-log4net/) while you would be implementing the steps explained above then ask specific related to your code snippet, so that it would be convenient to assist you further.